# How can I write to dmesg from command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, kernel, logs, dmesg

I'd like to write a statement to dmesg. How can I do this?

Comment: Two reasons I've wanted to do this before: (1) to see what "now is" in dmesg-timestamp format, and (2) to know when I last looked at dmesg.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `now` is seconds from boot, and I think it takes a kernel call to write to it so a userland program can't.

Comment: @Kevin, so you know without looking how many seconds have elapsed since you booted?

Comment: @Kevin it's the number of *microseconds* since boot, just formatted as seconds to make it easier to read for us humans.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Write to `/dev/kmsg` (not `/proc/kmsg` as suggested by @[Nils](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/11083/nils)).  See [`linux/kernel/printk/printk.c`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/printk/printk.c) `devkmsg_writev` for the kernel-side implementation and [`systemd/src/journal/journald-kmsg.c`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/journal/journald-kmsg.c) `server_forward_kmsg` for an example of usage.

Comment: It's not allowed on some system for non-root users (e.g.: Android kernel) :-(.

Comment: E.g. `date | sudo tee /dev/kmsg`

Comment: Worth noting, that while this will make the message appear in `dmesg`, however over a `netconsole` debugging utility *(where you'd expect to see the same content)* you will not see the message until you increase `dmesg` debugging level. For example `sudo dmesg -n 8` works.

Comment: As a n00b, I was pleasantly surprised that you have only to put a colon in your message if you want `dmesg` to highlight the prefix: `echo "BLAH: This is your message!" | sudo tee /dev/kmsg`.

Answer (score 21):

For BSDs:

```
logger -p kern.notice MESSAGE
```

(courtesy [Ian, freebsd-questions mailing list](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2011-March/228332.html))

or [other priorities](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?logger(1)).

For Linux:

```
su root -c 'echo MESSAGE > /dev/kmsg'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming nobody else comes up with an official way to do this ...

You can write a kernel module that calls the `printk` function. There's an example [here](http://www.crashcourse.ca/wiki/index.php/Writing_your_first_kernel_module) that might just do the job for you.

Comment: a. No need, others have written it already (e.g. [kecho](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~halfline/kecho/)).  b. **Really** no need for an extra module, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

--> You may write a C program as below:

test_mod.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    printk("Hello All\n This is a test init\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk("Good Bye");
}
```

--> make object file:

```
echo "obj-m := test_mod.o" > Makefile
```

--> compile by running :

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules`
```

--> load your module as below:

```
insmod ./test_mod.ko
```

see the output:

```
dmesg | tail
```

--> unload module:

```
rmmod test_mod.ko
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Add your message here" | sudo tee /dev/kmsg
```

Verify by running `dmesg -T`

Comment: This might have been better as an edit to [the accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35647/116858), which already suggests writing to `/dev/kmsg`.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood [man dmesg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html) correctly, you should be able to write to **/proc/kmsg**.

Comment: # echo "test" >> /proc/kmsg [yields =>]
-su: echo: write error: Input/output error